# How can I render monospace text in any font with FreeType 2?

Tags: freetype, freetype2

Given any typical font, not necessarily a monospace one, how can I render text in a monospace style? I've tried messing around with drawing the bitmaps of the glyphs individually, but I can never get the x and y alignment between glyphs right. I'm using OpenGL and python, but the answer should be adaptable to any graphics context or language.

Answer (score 1):

OK yep sorry I'm silly. I'm not even sure what I was doing wrong before. In case anyone equally as silly stumbles upon this, the simplest solution (in pseudocode) is just:

```
int charWidth = width of widest character in font;

void drawString(FT_Face face, string str, int xshift, int yshift) {
    x = 0;
    for (each character c in str) {
        FT_Load_Char(face, c, ...);
        draw the character at (xshift + x, yshift);
        x += charWidth;
    }
}
```

(It won't let me accept my own answer yet)

Comment: Freetype is returning a different glyph size for each character (basically removing any whitespace there might be around the glyph). Your solution doesn't take into account the fact that every character should be placed at a different baseline. Did you ever figure out how to deal with that? Also, you should be able to accept your answer now!

Comment: there's something like advance.x, too